# What is the best way to add data array in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

I have a state object with a category array in it. In this array of objects, one of the keys ("list") of the object is assigned an array.
What I need to do is

1. filter a specific object in the category array by name
2. add a new object to the "list" property (array) of the filtered object (keeping the old ones)

**Example**

```
const initialState = {
    category: [
        {
            name: "new",
            color: "#5236C1",
            list: [
                {
                    title: "name title",
                    about: "about",
                    imgLink: 'https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://mail.yandex.ru/',
                    url: 'https://www.yandex.ru'
                }, 
                 // there should be a new object
            ]
        },
```

*tried to do so*

```
const addBM = (state, payload) => {
    console.log(payload)
    const {url, title, about, cat} = payload
    let selectCatArr = state.category.filter((item) => item.name == cat)
    return {
        ...state,
        category: [...state.category, {list: [title, url, about ]}]
    }
}
```

**there should be a new object**

Comment: What do you want to do with the filtered array (`selectCatArr`)? Where does that come in? (it would be useful if you could show an example of your input, the payload object, and  your expected result)

Comment: Kinda related: you are writing a very old style of redux here, so you are probably following an outdated tutorial. In modern redux (*only when you use the official redux toolkit and createSlice/createReducer), you could simply `.push` into that array without having to take care about immutable modification yourself - the toolkit will do that for you. See [the official redux tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index) about this. Most other sources are severely outdated.
(Also, the rest of your code will also shrink down to 1/4 or so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modifed the addBM function and added some comments which explain the code.

```
const addBM = (state, payload) => {
    console.log(payload)
    const {url, title, about, cat} = payload

    // use map method instead of filter
    const modifiedCategory = state.category.map(categoryItem => {
        // only modify the category item if it's name matches the cat argument
        // otherwise return the original category item
        
        if (categoryItem.name == cat) {
            // create a copy of the category item object
            let modifiedCategoryItem = {
                ...categoryItem,
                // modify the list array of this object by
                // creating a copy of the array and
                // adding a new object with (url, title and about arguments) in this array
                list: [...categoryItem.list, {url, title, about}]
            };
            return modifiedCategoryItem;
        } else {
            return categoryItem;
        }
    });

    return {
        ...state,
        category: modifiedCategory
    }
};
```

Comment: @Imngz,Oh my god, now I'll try